# Selenium Webdriver stuck when find_element method called with a non-existed widget

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to test with selenium webdriver. My version of selenium is 2.33 and the browser is Firefox. The scripting language is python

Now when I call the method `find_element_by_xpath(blabla)` If the widget does not exist. The program just gets stuck there with no exception shown. It's just stuck. By the way I have tried `find_element_by_id`, `find_element_by_name`, `find_elements` and changed Firefox to 3.5, 14.0, 21.0, 22.0. The problem always shows up.

Anybody ever got this problem?
I just want an exception not just getting stuck. Help...

Answer (score 2):

**find_element_*** raises `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException` if element is not found.

**find_elements_*** return empty list if element is not found.

Both functions does not stuck.

According to [Selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html):

> 4.1. Locating by Id
>
> Use this when you know id attribute of an element. With this strategy, the first element with the id attribute
>   value matching the location will be returned. If no element has a
>   matching id attribute, **a NoSuchElementException will be raised.**
>
> ...
>
> 4.2. Locating by Name
>
> Use this when you know name attribute of an element. With this strategy, the first element with the name attribute
>   value matching the location will be returned. If no element has a
>   matching name attribute, **a NoSuchElementException will be raised.**

Comment: Thanks for your anwser.I see the exception most of the time. but truth is sometimes it's just stucked.I don't know why.if i change the xpath to an existent widget it won't stuck any more

Comment: Happened to me too, sometimes, when the page is not fully loaded it seems, thing is, maybe the page could load forever, thus, your script is stuck.
Im searching for a solution too, currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDriverWait function if you are sure that the element is on your document. You should define WebDriverWait at the beginning with `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait` and if you didn't define before `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`, then use `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "blabla")))`
That's all we need to do. I hope this will help you.

Comment: So that means i have to wait until the timeout?I just want a quick exception, using timeout would waste a lot of time to my work

Comment: I generally use Xpath for this kind of staff, more successful. If the page loads all the elements, selenium can find them. You need to find something (path,class_name etc.) you can find the element without exception, then you can skip this exception too.