# How to handle exceptions in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I trying to get selenium.common.exceptions but they are not getting detected.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def check_exists_by_css_selector(selector):
    try:
        global driver
        driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector)
    except NoSuchElementException :
        return False
    return True
```

I have also tried `except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:` but the result remains same.
The `check_exists_by_css_selector()` function always returns true no matter what the value of selector is.

Even the other exceptions such as `ElementNotVisibleException` are not working

Comment: you need selenium exception list? or want to handle them?

Comment: I already have selenium exception list from their documentation. I need an example to solve above problem.

Comment: What happens when you run your script without any exception handler? Is there any exception really raised?

Comment: Any particular reason you've placed your `return True` outside your catch block?

Comment: if there is not exception raised, it means that element exists. That is why there is `return true` outside exception block

Comment: got a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919503/selenium-webdriver-stuck-when-find-element-method-called-with-a-non-existed-widg?rq=1

Comment: only `find_element_...` methods raise exceptions `find_elements_...` methods return an empty list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution...

Only find_element_... methods raise exceptions, find_elements_... methods return an empty list